# Why is form.value empty in ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to get my form value in ngAfterViewInit. Unfortunately it's always empty. I'm experting something like: `{"name1":null, "name2": null}` but i get `{ }`.

The documentation says the following about `ngAfterViewInit`:

> called after initializing the component's views and child views.

I'm assuming the form is created at this point, but then why is my value empty?

My html:

```
<form novalidate #form="ngForm">
    // <Item 1...
    // <Item 2...


    <button type="submit" (click)="search()" class="btn btn-default">Zoeken</button>
</form>

//This is displaying the correct value
<div>
    <p>Form: {{ form.value | json }}</p>
    <p>Form status: {{ form.control.status }}</p>
</div>
```

Component:

```
export class BijComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    @ViewChild('form') form: FormGroup;


    constructor(private bijService: BijService, private sessionService: SessionService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Do stuff
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let v = JSON.stringify(this.form.value);// is `{ }`???
    }

    search(){
        //Search function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of `javascript`, let me explain a bit:

When you create your form, it creates an internal object to store form value using every field to set data.

But if the variable is never affected, its value is not `null` but `undefined`, which means that the variable doesn't exist.

That's why you get `{}` not `{"name1":null, "name2": null}`.

Comment: Then why doesn't it exist in `ngAfterViewInit` but does it exist in the `search` function?

Comment: what do you mean by "exist in the search function"? have you tried to `console.log(this.form.value)` inside `search()`?

Comment: Yes I have. It gives `{"name1":null, "name2": null}`. But I need that value in `ngAfterViewInit` or some other onCreate method

Comment: Have you tried with  `OnInit` hook? I don't see where the problem comes from. But there's a solution which is data binding your fields to the component (tell me if you want me to update answer to show an example)

Comment: same result in `ngOnInit`. I don't need the example. I already use the binding solution now.